# Calculate Mean and SEM across multiple columns by name

Tags: r

I am interested in calculating the mean and standard error of the mean (SEM) across multiple columns in R. Here is an example:

```
df<-data.frame(x_1=c(4,2,2), x_2=c(3,4,5), y_1=c(6,7,8), y_2 = c(8,8,8))
```

Here is the desired output:

```
output_df <- data.frame(x_mean=c(3.5,3,3.5), x_sem=c(0.35,0.71,1.06), y_mean=c(7,7.5,8), y_sem = c(0.71,0.35,0))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```r
df<-data.frame(x_1=c(4,2,2), x_2=c(3,4,5), y_1=c(6,7,8), y_2 = c(8,8,8))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowid, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", NA)) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(x:y, .fns = list(mean = mean, sem = function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   rowid x_mean x_sem y_mean y_sem
#>   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    3.5 0.354    7   0.707
#> 2     2    3   0.707    7.5 0.354
#> 3     3    3.5 1.06     8   0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(x_1=c(4,2,2), x_2=c(3,4,5), y_1=c(6,7,8), y_2 = c(8,8,8))
setDT(df)[, id := 1:.N]

vars <- c("x", "y")

df_melt <- melt(
  data = df,
  id.vars = "id", 
  measure.vars = patterns("^x_", "^y_"), 
  value.name = vars
)

Mean <- df_melt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = id, .SDcols = vars]
SEM <- df_melt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), by = id, .SDcols = vars]

names(Mean)[-1] <- paste0(names(Mean)[-1], "_mean", sep = "")
names(SEM)[-1] <- paste0(names(SEM)[-1], "_sem", sep = "")

Mean[SEM, on = "id"]
#>    id x_mean y_mean     x_sem     y_sem
#> 1:  1    3.5    7.0 0.3535534 0.7071068
#> 2:  2    3.0    7.5 0.7071068 0.3535534
#> 3:  3    3.5    8.0 1.0606602 0.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

specify the calculation formula SEM.
perhaps you need a formula

`sem = function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))`